# Visual Studio 2013 copying Microsoft .pdb folders and files to one above target directory at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I have a project which compiles and builds fine. However, at runtime, VS seems to copy a bunch of Microsoft PDB files to `.\$(TargetDir)\..\` and I cannot quite figure out why this might be. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is my output folder before (each folder is a project)
[image]

Here it is after runtime:
[image]

**EDIT**

Something interesting to note, after I build a release version, I try to run the program. However, before the program runs, it generates `Debug` folder where it stores more symbol files.

Comment: Check `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols` settings (not sure about exact settings location in VS 2012 though)